# Regex appears properly formed, but not ouputting expected results in grep

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to search my codebase for instances of the following pattern:

```
m_vParts[foo] =
```

And similar instances with varying whitespace. So I can up with this regex:

```
m_vParts\[.*\]\s*=[^=]\s*
```

When I test this at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and other regex-tester type sites, it finds exactly what I want. However, when I actually `grep` (or `egrep`) I get no results. My guess is my regex isn't well-formed for `grep`'s dialect of regexes, but I'm not sure exactly where I'm off.

Here is the actual command I give:

```
[e]grep -Irn "m_vParts\[.*\]\s*=[^=]\s*" .
```

I've tried with both single and double quotes.

Here's a small sample of code that is exemplary of the codebase:

```
pcTab->m_vParts[iLastPart] = pcPart;
if ( m_pcCurrentTab->m_vParts[i]== pcPart )
```

I would expect that the first line would be a match, and the second line would not.

Also, I should note that I'm using GnuWin32 grep on Windows 7 x64.

Thanks in advance for any guidance here; very much trying to avoid the non-automated search :)

Comment: Hmmm, `egrep -Irn "m_vParts\[.*\]\s*=[^=]\s*" .` gives a hit on my Ubuntu box...

Comment: You say you're running this command on Windows. How exactly are you running it? Like, is this in Bash, or in the straight-up Windows shell, or . . . ?

Comment: It's in the Windows shell, using a windows port of some linux tools such as grep in the GnuWin32 package. I suppose it could be an issue with this package, since it seems people are able to get the expected results on linux boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add quotes around the re:

```
$ vim 1.txt
$ egrep 'm_vParts\[.*\]\s*=[^=]\s*' 1.txt
pcTab->m_vParts[iLastPart] = pcPart;
```

As you can see, all works.

Comment: Sorry again, as I mentioned above, I have tried this but forgot to put it in the original post.

Comment: Marking this as the answer, since it is a correct regex, in case anyone else is looking for something similar. I believe my issue lies in the Windows port of the grep tool